Is 1 hour and 20 minutes enough time to make an international layover in El Dorado International in Bogota
I am flying from Lima, Peru to Miami with an 1:20 layover in Bogota. Since this is my first time flying into Colombia as an American Citizen, I am a bit nervous. The trip is booked all on one ticket through Avianca, but I am unsure if I would need to go through security or customs. Will an hour and 20 minutes be enough to make it through ?
Additionally, I believe American Citizens are on Colombia's Visa Exception list, meaning that I would not need to apply for a transit Visa since I am only passing through to make a connection. If anybody could clear this up for me as well, that would be greatly appreciated!

It's tight.
Since Avianca sold you this as a single ticket, you have a good chance of making it but there is no guarantee and little room for error or anything unusual.
I found the airport to be a bit on the chaotic and disorganized side and Avianca is also not know as the most efficient airline to grace the skies, so I think this itinerary has a "higher than usual" connection risk.
If you miss it, Avianca is required to take care of you and put you on the next available flight. This may be on the next day. If you need to stay over night, Avianca should put you up in a hotel, but that depends a bit on your negotiating skills and your legal ability to enter Columbia.

I am unsure if I would need to go through security or customs.

You definitely will go through security and quite likely through an extra doc check for US bound passengers.
You should not need to go through immigrations or customs, nor should you need a transit visa, but precise info around this is murky and I recommend putting your specific details in here: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm
